# Phoenix Securecore BIOS not detecting USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios, phoenix

I'm trying to boot Linux from an external USB on a Samsung laptop but the BIOS (Phoenix Securecore Tiano Setup P03ABH Version) doesn't recognise any USB or other boot options that aren't the WBM no matter what I change.

Here are some pictures of the BIOS menu:

[SysInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lyZa.jpg)

[Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnGM8.jpg)

[Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKnxb.jpg)

[Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jImGO.jpg)

[Boot Device Priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6axM.jpg)

[Exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHXd7.jpg)

I can't find any firmware upgrades on the internet and, from what I've seen, [someone in a Korean blog](http://blog.daum.net/_blog/BlogTypeView.do?blogid=0Hvc2&articleno=249068&_bloghome_menu=recentthumb) can see all the options without problems while I can't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Boot Device Priority screenshot seems to be identical to the Boot screenshot. Can you please add the correct one?

Comment: @Nassbirne Fixed!